# Crear BD mysql desde php con consultas preparadas

Tags: php, mysql

mi problema es que estoy intentando crear una BD desde php, con consultas preparadas, pero mysql me da error.

El código PHP es:

```
private static $sql = array(

    'create database :nombreBD default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;',
    'create user :usuario identified by :clave;',
    'grant all on :nombreBD.* to :usuario;',
    'flush privileges;',
    'use :nombreBD;'
);

static function createScheme(MySql $mysql, $database, $user, $password) {

    $arrayParametros = array(
        0 => array('nombreBD' => htmlentities($database, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8')),            
        1 => array('usuario' => $user,
                   'clave' => $password),
        2 => array('nombreBD' => htmlentities($database, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8'), 
                    'usuario' => $user),
        4 => array('nombreBD' => htmlentities($database, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8'))  
    );

    foreach (self::$sql as $indice => $sentencia) {
        $parametros = array();
        if(isset($arrayParametros[$indice])) {
            $parametros = $arrayParametros[$indice];
        } 
        $mysql->execute($sentencia, $parametros);
    }
}
```

Pero a la hora me da los siguientes errores:

> create database :nombreBD default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
>   array (
>    'nombreBD' => 'BaseDatos',
>   )
>   array (
>    0 => '42000',
>    1 => 1064,
>    2 => 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\'Albayda\' default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci\' at line 1',
>   )

El problema es que cuando en phpMyAdmin entro el comando por mysql, si ponemos comillas da error.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Qué es "Albayda"? (el valor que aparece en el mensaje de error) ¿Con cuál de los parámetros se corresponde?

Comment: También sería importante que compartieras el código de tu función `execute` para ver cómo se asocian los valores a la sentencia SQL.

Comment: Hola Alvaro, "Albayda" es el nombre que en este caso se ha introducido en el formulario para la base de datos.

Comment: Función execute:

Comment: function execute($sql, array $parametros = array()) {
 
       $this->sentencia = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);                                foreach ($parametros as $nombreDelParametro => $valorDelParametro) {
            $this->sentencia->bindValue($nombreDelParametro, $valorDelParametro);
        }